# implenting WSDL and SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have a hard time making a phpscript of the WSDL code found on  http://network.thinkaction.com/api/soap_affiliate.php?wsdl

It is a directtrack code and I don't recieve any when I use the script below. I have just made an incentive based website so I have to see who with what e-mail has completed a survey and how much he completed from day 1 to day 12.

```
<?php

   $url = "http://network.thinkaction.com/api/soap_affiliate.php?wsdl"; 
   $client = new SoapClient("$url"); 
   $result = $client->optionalInfo(
     array('client' => '000000', 
           'add_code' => 'CD00000', 
           'password' => '000000000000000')
     ); 

   echo ('$results');    
?>
```

Hope someone can help me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your client code and password aren't here, so I can't run the code to test it out, a few observations.

- http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html is a great way to get a look at how a SOAP API should work, when I run in to trouble I often execute calls there first.
- Your code will currently print $results literally. I would suggest var_dump($results); during development and testing.